# how to sort numerical arraylist in ascending order

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

I have an `ArrayList` which I have sorted using `Collections.sort`. 
But the outcome looks like down below. How do I get it to be ascending order?

`[0, 1, 11, 12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 14, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 19, 2, 2, 20, 20, 20, 21, 21, 22, 4, 7, 7, 7, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9]`

Comment: Adding the language tags such as Python, Ruby, Perl will get you better answers.

Comment: The output indicates you're sorting character data, not numeric ones. They're in the proper order for characters. If you want to order them as numbers, either convert them to integers or add the leading (or trailing) zero to make them all two digits.

Comment: @Ken White Just to understand, how do you say output is sorted on character & they are in order

Comment: I do not know Java but i guess it should be something like this `testList.sort((a, b) -> Double.compare(b, a))`

Comment: They're in proper order when sorted as characters, exactly as I said. Copy the values, paste them into Excel in a column formatted as text, and ask Excel to sort them, and you'll get the same exact order you've shown. Format them as numbers, and you'll get a different sort. Numbers don't need or have (or allow) a leading zero.

Comment: Gnarf. 4 hours; and nobody tells you the one sane thing: dont **tell** us what you did; create a  [mcve] and show us your code. If you were using a `List<Number>` (number meaning, well a number type); then Collections.sort() will do proper sorting. So you must be doing something else. But nobody can know without seeing your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your `ArrayList` contains strings instead of numbers. You can sort it in numerical order by passing a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html) to the [`sort()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#sort-java.util.Comparator-) method.

In java 8, you can use [`Comparator.comparingInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html#comparingInt-java.util.function.ToIntFunction-) to do the actual comparision, in combination with the [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt-java.lang.String-) method to perform the conversion from string to int:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
// ... add values    

list.sort(Comparator.comparingInt(Integer::parseInt));
```

Answer (score 2):

Java 8:

```
List<String> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
    // add numbers...
    Collections.sort(numbers, Comparator.comparing(Integer::valueOf));
```

Answer (score 1):

`Collections.sort` method works fine if you don't mixed numeric and string types;
 Here's an example:

```
       import java.util.*;
       public class ArrayListOfIntegers  {

        public static void main(String args[]){
        ArrayList<Integer> arraylist = new ArrayList<>();
        arraylist.add(12);
        arraylist.add(0);
        arraylist.add(12);
        arraylist.add(1);
        arraylist.add(12);
        arraylist.add(11);
       /* ArrayList before the sorting*/
        System.out.println("Before Sorting:");
        for(int counter: arraylist){
             System.out.println(counter);
         }

        /* Sorting of arraylist using Collections.sort*/
           Collections.sort(arraylist);

        /* ArrayList after sorting*/
         System.out.println("After Sorting:");
         for(int counter: arraylist){
             System.out.println(counter);
         }
      }
   }
```

Output :[image]

Good luck;

Answer (score 0):

**Java7:** `Collections.sort()` methods works differently for String and Integer data types.

I assume that you have `ArrayList<String>`. One solution is to convert it to `ArrayList<Integer>` and then pass through `Collections.sort()`

```
    ArrayList<String> strList = new ArrayList<String>();
    strList.add("0");
    strList.add("1");
    strList.add("11");
    strList.add("12");
    strList.add("2");
    strList.add("02");
    strList.add("004");
    strList.add("9");
    strList.add("20");

    System.out.println("strList Unsorted :" + strList);
    Collections.sort(strList);
    System.out.println("strList Sorted :" + strList);

    //Convert ArrayList<String> to ArrayList<Integer>
    List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>(strList.size());
    for (String strValue : strList) {
        intList.add(Integer.parseInt(strValue));
    }

    System.out.println("intList Unsorted :" + intList);
    Collections.sort(intList);
    System.out.println("intList Sorted :" + intList);
```

[image]